# my android app works very slow

Tags: java, android

Hello i'm creating an app to scan buisness cards, it has lot of views but one works very slow it has 19 buttons. Is it possible that slow working of my app is caused by this number of buttons? I've tried to put listeners outside of onCreate but it didn't help. This is my java file conected to this view:

```
public class Szczegoly extends Activity {
long contactID;
Bitmap contactFoto;
int imagebig=0;
int w;
Contact contact;
EditText tv1;
EditText tv2;
EditText tv3;
EditText tv4;
EditText tv5;
ImageView i;
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button b9;
Button b10;
Context to;
Button accept1;
Button accept2;
Button accept3;
Button accept4;
Button accept5;
Button cancel1;
Button cancel2;
Button cancel3;
Button cancel4;
Button cancel5;
Context context;

OnClickListener accept1listener = new OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==1)
        {
            contact.savedata_nr(edit_nr,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,context);
            closeEdit();
        }           
    }
};

OnClickListener accept2listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==2)
        {
            contact.savedata_nr(edit_nr,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,context);
            closeEdit();
        }            
    }
};

OnClickListener accept3listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==3)
        {
            contact.savedata_nr(edit_nr,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,context);
            closeEdit();
        }            
    }
};
OnClickListener accept4listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==4)
        {
            contact.savedata_nr(edit_nr,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,context);
            closeEdit();
        }            
    }
};
OnClickListener accept5listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==5)
        {
            contact.savedata_nr(edit_nr,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,context);
            closeEdit();
        }            
    }
};
OnClickListener cancel1listener = new OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
        closeEdit();
    }
};
OnClickListener cancel2listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
        closeEdit();
    }
};
OnClickListener cancel3listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
        closeEdit();
    }
};
OnClickListener cancel4listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
        closeEdit();
    }
};
OnClickListener cancel5listener = new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
        closeEdit();
    }
};

OnClickListener b1lisner = new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
            finish();
        }               
    }
};
OnClickListener b2lisner = new OnClickListener() {                  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
            contact.delete();
            finish();
        }               
    }
};
OnClickListener b3lisner = new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
        }               
    }
};
OnClickListener b4lisner = new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
            Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:"+contact.Phone1);    
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call);
            startActivity(intent);
        }               
    }
};
OnClickListener b5lisner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
        }

    }
};
OnClickListener b6lisner = new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
            if(tv1.isEnabled())
            {
                tv1.setSelected(false);
                tv1.setEnabled(false);
            }

            else
            {

                cancel1.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                accept1.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                b6.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                tv1.setEnabled(true);
                tv1.setSelected(true);
                tv1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                tv1.requestFocus();
                tv1.setSelection(tv1.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }

            }
            edit_nr= 1;
        }
    }
};
OnClickListener b7lisner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0)
        {
            if(tv2.isEnabled())
                tv2.setEnabled(false);
            else
            {


                cancel2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                accept2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                b7.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                 tv2.setEnabled(true);
                tv2.setSelected(true);
                tv2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                tv2.requestFocus();
                tv2.setSelection(tv2.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }
            edit_nr= 2;
        }

    }
};
OnClickListener b8lisner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr == 0)
        {
            if(tv3.isEnabled())
                tv3.setEnabled(false);
            else
            {
                cancel3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                accept3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                b8.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                tv3.setEnabled(true);
                tv3.setEnabled(true);
                tv3.setSelected(true);
                tv3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                tv3.requestFocus();
                tv3.setSelection(tv3.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }
            edit_nr=3;
        }

    }
};
OnClickListener b9lisner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr ==0 )
        {
            if(tv4.isEnabled())
                tv4.setEnabled(false);
            else
            {                   
                cancel4.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                accept4.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                b9.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                tv4.setEnabled(true);
                tv4.setEnabled(true);
                tv4.setSelected(true);
                tv4.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);                  
                tv4.requestFocus();
                tv4.setSelection(tv4.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }                
            edit_nr= 4;
        }
    }
};
OnClickListener b10lisner = new OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edit_nr==0)
        {
            if(tv5.isEnabled())
                tv5.setEnabled(false);
            else
            {                   
                cancel5.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                accept5.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                b10.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                tv5.setEnabled(true);
                tv5.setEnabled(true);
                tv5.setSelected(true);
                tv5.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);                  
                tv5.requestFocus();
                tv5.setSelection(tv5.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) 
                {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }                
        edit_nr= 5;
        }
    }
};
int edit_nr=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_szczegoly);
    Log.d("dupa","dupa1");
    context = this;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    contactID = intent.getLongExtra("contactID", 0);
    contact = new Contact(contactID, this);
    tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    tv4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    tv5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    tv1.setText(contact.FirstName);
    tv2.setText(contact.LastName);
    tv3.setText(contact.Phone1);
    tv4.setText(contact.Phone2);
    tv5.setText(contact.EmaiL);
    accept1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept1);
    accept2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept2);
    accept3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept3);
    accept4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept4);
    accept5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept5);
    cancel1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel1);
    cancel2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel2);
    cancel3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel3);
    cancel4 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel4);
    cancel5 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel5);


}

public void closeEdit()
{
    tv1.setSelected(false);
    tv1.setEnabled(false);
    tv2.setSelected(false);
    tv2.setEnabled(false);
    tv3.setSelected(false);
    tv3.setEnabled(false);
    tv4.setSelected(false);
    tv4.setEnabled(false);
    tv5.setSelected(false);
    tv5.setEnabled(false);
    cancel1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    accept1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    b6.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    cancel2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    accept2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    b7.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    cancel3.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    accept3.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    b8.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    cancel4.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    accept4.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    b9.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    cancel5.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    accept5.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    b10.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    edit_nr=0;
}



public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  
    Log.d("dupa","dupa");
    Point size = new Point();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    to = this;
    w = size.x;
    contactFoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(contact.photo, w, (int) (w*contact.photo.getHeight()/contact.photo.getWidth()), true);      
    i.setImageBitmap(contactFoto);
    accept1.setOnClickListener(accept1listener);        
    accept2.setOnClickListener(accept2listener);
    accept3.setOnClickListener(accept3listener);        
    accept4.setOnClickListener(accept4listener);        
    accept5.setOnClickListener(accept5listener);
    cancel1.setOnClickListener(cancel1listener);
    cancel2.setOnClickListener(cancel2listener); 
    cancel3.setOnClickListener(cancel3listener);
    cancel4.setOnClickListener(cancel4listener);
    cancel5.setOnClickListener(cancel5listener);
    b1.setOnClickListener(b1lisner);
    b2.setOnClickListener(b2lisner);
    b3.setOnClickListener(b3lisner);
    b4.setOnClickListener(b4lisner);
    b5.setOnClickListener(b5lisner);
    b6.setOnClickListener(b6lisner);
    b7.setOnClickListener(b7lisner);
    b8.setOnClickListener(b8lisner);
    b9.setOnClickListener(b9lisner);
    b10.setOnClickListener(b10lisner);

}
```

}

Comment: `contactFoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(contact.photo, w, (int) (w*contact.photo.getHeight()/contact.photo.getWidth()), true);` is probably not very fast.

Comment: The buttons are probably not causing the slowness, but there is a lot redundant code you don't need. You should definitely work on refactoring it.

Answer (score 0):

The number of buttons by itself is not a likely cause of slowness. However, from the code it seems as if many actions from listeners (ie `contact.savedata_nr`) might be running on the main/UI thread which could cause slowness, depending on what happens when these methods are called. As mentioned in the comment, creating Bitmap might be better task to be carried out in the background as well.

To fix this, you should review your code and see what can be run in the background thread instead. Operations like saving can be done on the background thread, and then any updates to the GUI after these should be carried out on UI thread. If the background operation takes a long time, it's a good idea to up a progress indicator to show the user that something is happening and that the screen isn't just stuck. 
You can read about Android threading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

The basic example would be:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //put background code here
        contact.save(...)

        //after background task is finished, update the UI
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                //put UI code here
                textview.setText(...);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```